# Google cloud load balancer port 80, to VM instances serving port 9000

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I'm new in GCE, and I am confused about setting up the load balancer.

If I have two instances, serving on Port 9000, I want to setup a balancer that accepts on port 80, then route requests to my instances in port 9000..

a diagram like this..

```
LB:port:80 -> VM:port:9000
```

I have other load balancers from other providers which has a settings like pointing to VM's port. but in GCE, I cant seem to find it, or I am missing something..

I hope I am making a sense, here. thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible in GCE to do a port rewriting. As a workaround I use [port forwarding using iptables](http://www.fclose.com/816/port-forwarding-using-iptables/)
Then in GCE, you can create a health check on port 9000, your target pool will have your instances listing on port 9000 and your forwarding rule will be on port 80 with your target pool.

Another workaround will be to run HAProxy on the instance to locally forward port 80 on the instance to port 9000.

Comment: is that so, it's clear to me now. looks like I have to put an extra work in there. I'm not familiar with iptables, or HAProxy, but I will try. how inconvenient it is. thanks for the time and advice then!, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is HTTP-based (looks like it), then please have a look at the new HTTP load balancing announced in June. It can take incoming traffic at port 80 and forward to a user-specified port (eg. port 9000) on the backend. The doc link for the command is here:

https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#creating_a_backend_service

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. that is sad, we are now using HAproxy. and apparently, we dont use gce currently due to load balancer setup issues. we did not have enough time searching around as we were in a tight schedule. all we wanted was, set a port 80 and forward request to go_webservers. this can be done easily in aws or HAproxy that we all know well. thanks for the comment again, i might play it once again or try some time :D

Comment: And then again, they charge a flat fee for just using even one port forwarding that I didn't even know there would be a charge for ! Ridic. More than the charge for the instance itself !