# Google Cloud Load balancer (exclude specific port)

Tags: routes, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I just setup google Cloud's https load balancer and it seems to be working correctly (it's super fast). However I'm not able to access SSL protected pages on a specific port anymore.

e.g. 
https://www.example.com (works fine)
https://www.example.com:8443 (does not work anymore with the load balancer enabled)

**Current settings:**
www pointed to load balancers IP.

Is it possible to make an exclusion in the load balancer for a specific port (e.g. 8443 / 8447) so traffic get redirected directly to the correct server ip? (e.g. bypass the load balancer).

Thank you for your help!

~ Luc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to exclude any port like this.

Moreover, in my understanding, Google Load Balancing provides support for listening on specific ports only ( 80/8080 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPs ). One can not provide custom ports in it's configuration.

If you want to directly access the service running on 8443, you can always call the instance directly using instance's ip or hostname ( instance-host:8443 ).

If you want to load balance the service, then you have two options:

1. Run service on standard port only.
2. Use port forwarding on the instance or local proxy like HAProxy ( [Google cloud load balancer port 80, to VM instances serving port 9000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656161/google-cloud-load-balancer-port-80-to-vm-instances-serving-port-9000) ).

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Worked around the issue by setting the A record directly to the server ip and the www the the load balancers IP.