# How to redirect traffic from port 80 to 8080 - Load balancer - Cloud DNS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns, gcp-load-balancer

I have a requirement similar to this post,

[Google cloud load balancer port 80, to VM instances serving port 9000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656161/google-cloud-load-balancer-port-80-to-vm-instances-serving-port-9000)

I like one of the answers (not the accepted), but how to do it ? or is there an alternate way ?

> " If your app is HTTP-based (looks like it), then please have a look
> at the new HTTP load balancing announced in June. It can take incoming
> traffic at port 80 and forward to a user-specified port (eg. port
> 9000) on the backend. The doc link for the command is here:
>
> [https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#creating_a_backend_service"](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#creating_a_backend_service%22)

I dont want to create statis IP after static IP and loose track

Scenario:
A Compute Engine with an application running on port 8080 or 8043  (firewall open for 8080 and 8443 , has static IP )

Now I want to hook it a domain.

**Problem**:

I have to specify port number - like http://mywebsite:8080

**Goal**: Allow use like http://mywebsite

Please can I ask how Cloud DNS and Load Balancer work. Are both needed for my scenario? help me connect the dots.
Thanks

Note: Application works on 8080 only (wont run on 80)

Answer (score 1):

DNS knows nothing about port numbers (except for special record types). DNS is a hostname to IP address translation service.

You can either use a proxy/load-balancer to proxy port 80 to 8080 or configure your app to run on port 80.

Port 80 requires permission to use. For Linux this means configuring your application to run with system privileges or starting the application with `sudo`.

Most applications that run on non-standard ports have a web server in front of them such as Apache or Nginx. The web server proxies port 80 to 8080 and provides a more resilient Internet facing service.

> I don't want to create static IP after static IP and lose track

Unfortunately, you will need to manage your services and their resources. If you deploy a load balancer, then you can usually use private IP addresses for the compute instances. Only the load balancer requires a public IP address. The load balancer will proxy port 80 to 8080.

However, assuming that your requirements are small, you can assign a public IP address to the instance, install Apache or Nginx, and run your application on port 8080.

Today, it is rare that Internet-facing web services do not support HTTPS (port 443). Using a load balancer simplifies configuring TLS and certificate management. You can also configure TLS in Apache/Nginx and Let's Encrypt. That removes the requirement that your app supports TLS directly on something like port 8443.

Comment: I can make my application run on https (8443). Can you please give details about the steps . I did something (worrying about costs) and released a static ip. I can create a letsencrypt certificate for my domain name, and create a CNAME record on domain. Now on google cloud side, do i need CloudDNS or use a load balancer or both needed?. If load balancer how to do - front end , backend ? or just backend. I am getting confused there

Comment: @KrisSwat - create a new post for each of your problems - one problem per post.

Comment: my goal have this bits.( I did not edit my question. ) . I did see a question you answered on https front end backend, but if I ask that again, I get downvotes.

Comment: @KrisSwat - I have answered your question. You should be using Apache, Nginx, proxy, or load balancer. That way you do not need to configure port 8443.  Otherwise, configuring port 8443 with TLS requires modifying your code. You did not post any code. Remember, one well-defined question per post.

Comment: I got your suggestion. coming to answer nginx. Install nginx and it runs automatically, how to redirect traffic as asked in the question

Answer (score -1):

I found this article and it works - https://eladnava.com/binding-nodejs-port-80-using-nginx/

Steps: (sudo apt-get update)

sudo apt-get install nginx

**remove default**

sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

**create new - node folder**

sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/node

<<<<<< add this to the file  update domain name , port of your app ...8080 or other>>>>>

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name somedomain.co.uk;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
    }
}
```

**create a symbolic link:**

sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/node /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/node

**Restart nginx**

sudo service nginx restart

Credits to original author - Elad Nava